# Split a List of Pairs into two lists - list of first and a list of second using RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

If I have an Observable of Pairs: `Observable<Pair<String, String>> source = ...`
and I call `toList()` on it to get a list of pairs, is there a way to transform it thereafter to two separate lists - a list of firsts and a list of seconds? Meaning, do something like this but using Rx operators:

```
Observable<Pair<String, String>> source = ...;
List<String> allFirsts = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> allSeconds = new ArrayList<>();

for (Pair p : source.toList()) {
 allFirsts.add(p.first);
 allSeconds.add(p.second);
}
```

Comment: Use share operator so you can split your observable into two others that are sharing upstream `val shared = source.toList().share()
val first = shared.map{extract first item from pair}
val second = shared.map{extract second item from pair}`

Comment: @Than can you rewrite your comment as an answer? That would allow the OP to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`collect` the items into a `Pair<List<String>, List<String>>`:

```
source.collect(
    () -> new Pair<List<String>,List<String>>(
        new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<String>()),
    (collection, pair) -> {
        collection.first.add(pair.first);
        collection.second.add(pair.second); 
     });
```